# Mimic CMYK plates offset with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make a visual disturbance effect on certain words in the text of my page, to mimic on-screen the calibration / offset errors that can occur when printing posters, magazines…

The idea is to randomly select a target word in the text, then wrap it in a `<span class="cmyk intensity-max">`. Then I would wrap the adjacent words in `<span class="cmyk intensity-medium">` and following in `<span class="cmyk intensity-min">`. The goal is to disturb a zone in the text and not a single word (I’m not really satisfied with my idea to atteign progressivity in the disturbance).

Then, I got a function that clones the content of the span three times, affects a relative position to the initial span, and absolute position and c/m/y colors to the other.

My question is about the best way to achieve this effect, in terms of performance, and about how to deal with the internal markup of the text (links, strongs, ems).

Comment: It's hard to suggest performance improvements without seeing the code you've written.

Comment: The code I’ve written uses such bad ideas that I don’t dare to show it… I split the text in <p>, then each <p> in "words" (space separated strings – that breaks the html when the word is a html tag, for example), then use a regExp to target this word and wrap it in my first span. And I got no idea on how to target adjacent words. I will try, but would need a base to start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo of occurred printing errors :)

### [DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/odoxoh/2/edit)

Using CSS:

```
  .errata{    
     color: black;
     text-shadow: 2px 0 cyan, -1px -1px magenta, 1px 2px yellow;
  }
```

It's not perfect but you can play around this idea.

Comment: Thank you for the css-only approach which is far better than my span duplication. But my real problem is to target a word and its adjacent ones.

Comment: Still not achieved… But I found a great way to select a “text node” within the DOM : https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText

Comment: Thanks, Roko. It’s approximately what I did. The search-for-a-word way leads to a behaviour I didn’t expected at start. It highlights each occurrence of the chosen word. I had to restrict to the first/nth occurrence. but my final goal, which was to achieve a progressive effect on neighbour words is still not there. Must admit that there’s only the need for a little regexp to catch the previous and next words (and that I did’nt tried really hard…).